# Selecionar todos itens com mesmo Id na mesma tabela

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, banco-de-dados, entity-framework

Muito bem , vou tentar ser o mais claro possivel.Eu tenho a tabela estoque onde vai ter lá varios produtos -> ProdutoId e sua Quantidade. Na mesma tabela o produtoId pode se repetir com uma quantidade diferente, no meu código atual eu só consigo pegar a primeira quantidade na tabela mas não consigo pegar a outra e somar as duas. uso entity framework usando lambda.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
            Estoque estoque = db.Estoque.Where(x => x.ProdutoId == model.ProdutoId).FirstOrDefault();
        int qtdEstoque = estoque.Quantidade;
```

Retorna =10 sendo que tinha que ser Quantidade = 30

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não vai conseguir somar as duas quantidades dessa forma, a melhor maneira de resolver isso seria, ao invés de usar o `FirstOrDefault()`, usar o `ToList()`para fazer a consulta, criando assim uma Lista de Estoques do mesmo `Produto Id`.Então trabalhar com essa lista, fazer um `ForEach` nela e somar as Quantidades. Algo assim:

```
var estoques = db.Estoque.Where(x => x.ProdutoId == model.ProdutoId).ToList();

int quantidadeEstoque = 0;

foreach(var estoque in estoques){
            quantidadeEstoque += estoque.Quantidade;
};
```

Dessa forma você consegue pegar todos os estoques com o menos `Produto_Id`.

Comment: Obrigado, era exatamente isso que precisava, eu tinha conseguido fazer usando uma gambiara feia aqui, mas seu código ficou mais limpo.vlw